# Stop users from navigating to restricted pages C# Web Application

Tags: c#, url, web-applications, model-view-controller

I have a finished web application. The user can navigate through the application as intended. I do however want to restrict the user from freely navigating through any page on the site by typing anything they want to in the url.

For example, if the user wants to use the site to buy a blue book, they would go to the homepage (www.buybooks.com), search for blue book (www.buybooks.com/search), select the book (www.buybooks.com/bluebook and then follow a number of other steps to pay for it. If the blue book is out of stock, it will be displayed in the search results. But I want to prevent the user from navigating to 'www.buybooks.com/bluebook) when it is out of stock.

Is there a standard method for doing this? I can't find any relevant information online.

Thanks, Kimberley

Comment: Why block the page? Instead I think it's better to disable a purchase/add to cart button. That way it's not unclear if the product is just out of stock or not supplied by you anymore.

Comment: The purchase/add button is disabled, but they are still able to navigate to the page by adding "bluebook" to "www.buybooks.com".

Comment: They end up being able to navigate to www.buybooks.com/bluebook whether or not the button is enabled/disabled

Comment: Well of course they will, the button being disabled just prevents them adding to cart and not from viewing it. My reasoning for not hiding it is due to potential customer confusion and SEO problems. If you're sure you want to do this though, do a redirect if the stock level is below a certain threshold

Comment: I want to display an error message when this happens

Comment: Okay how about using the stock check levels to display an error message.

Answer (score -1):

you can use asp.net membership provider, then you can use roles and restrict users to purchased book pages, mean
when they buy the book change their roles to purchased one.. 
but for that you need to create folders for each book and apply restrictions on them.
for asp.net memberships
goto asp.net website option under build menu.

Comment: How does this answer the question? I think you may have picked the user up wrongly.

Comment: ok so didn't i mention the solution, isn't asp.net membership roles can be used to restrict the pages ??

Comment: I have no idea, if you clarify in your answer and include samples of code etc I might understand where you're coming from but as it stands, you're completely off the mark.